# Magento 2: How to decrements item qty?

Tags: magento2, quantity, quoteitem

I want to decrements item qty programmatically.

```
    $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
    $qty = $item->getQty();

    if($qty > 0) {
        $newqty = ($qty - 1);
        $item->setQty($newqty);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $item->save();
        $this->cart->save();
    }
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code:**

```
$item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
if($item){
   $qty = $item->getQty();  
    if($qty > 2) {
        $newqty = ($qty - 1);
        $item->setQty($newqty);
        $item->save();
    }    
}
$this->cart->getQuote()->save();
```

Also, you have to Update Mini Cart using *sections.xml*  When you hitting  this above code.

See more how to apply Update Mini Cart   https://webkul.com/blog/update-mini-cart-magento2/